# Multi Value in Query Select PrestoDB

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to perfom some query to Prestodb like this:

```
SELECT *    
FROM (
     VALUES
     concat('<a href="https:test?preselect_filters=',
     url_encode(concat('{"27":{','"column_name":["', CAST({{ "'" + 
     "','".join(filter_values('column_name', concat('#value1', '#value2'))) + 
     "'" }} AS VARCHAR), '"]', ',','}}')), 
     '#TAB-bEGT8cU5h">Qun', '</a>')
         ) dashboard_link (links)
```

my problem is concat('#value1','#value2'), any idea to select an array of values?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve and what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Hi @MartinTraverso many thanks for your support, my idea is to create a select with multi values in input, the output should be all records with the values in input.

Comment: Hi @MartinTraverso if I have '"name":["', {{ "'" + "','".join(filter_values('name', '#value')) + "'" }}, '"]', ',' is it possible to add more #value ex. #value1, #value2,...,#valueN?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
select * from (values concat(ARRAY [1,2,3], ARRAY [4,5,6]));
```

You can refer to [prestodb doc](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html)